# Why language of weekday and month in strftime('%a %A %b %B') change after creating a pyplot figure?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, locale

I'm running a script which first shows *weekday* and *month* of `datetime.now()`, then creates a pyplot figure with `plt.figure()`, and finally shows again *weekday* and *month* of `datetime.now()`. The language of *weekday* and *month* **changed from English to French** after creating the figure. Does someone know why? Thanks.

**Edit:** I added print of `locale.getlocale()` to the code for more information. It seems that at the beginning locale is 'fr_FR.utf8', though, print time in English...

```
# coding: utf8

from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import locale

t1 = datetime.now()

print('\n', locale.getlocale())
print(t1.strftime('%a %A %b %B'))

print('\n Creating figure...')
fig = plt.figure()
plt.close(fig)

print('\n', locale.getlocale())
print(t1.strftime('%a %A %b %B'))

print("\n Setting locale to 'en_US.utf8'...")
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')

print('\n', locale.getlocale())
print(t1.strftime('%a %A %b %B'))
```

The result I get is:

```
 ('fr_FR', 'UTF-8')
Wed Wednesday Feb February

 Creating figure...

 ('fr_FR', 'UTF-8')
mer. mercredi févr. février

 Setting locale to 'en_US.utf8'...

 ('en_US', 'UTF-8')
Wed Wednesday Feb February
```

Comment: is this your complete code.. with above it shouldn't print datetime in french.  paste complete code

Comment: Yes, this is my complete code. Thanks for your help.